# VisibleWhen for Eclipse project selected or any file/folder in project selected

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I want to show a particular menu contribution when user selects a particular project with project nature *customnature* . User can select any file or folder in the project with project nature *customnature* and it will show the menu also.

Currently I have the visibleWhen for the menu contribution as following:

```xml
        <visibleWhen
             checkEnabled="false">
          <with
                variable="activeMenuSelection">
                <iterate>
                    <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
                         <and>
                         <test
                         property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
                         value="customnature">
                         </test>
                         </and>
                    </adapt>
             </iterate>
                <count
                      value="1">
                </count>
          </with>
       </visibleWhen>
```

This configuration successfully show menu when selecting project folder only.

Please give me some pointer to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieve it using property tester, the class is as below:

```
public class ProjectNaturePropertyTester extends PropertyTester {

@Override
public boolean test(Object receiver, String property, Object[] args,
        Object expectedValue) {

    IResource rsc=(IResource)receiver;
    try {
        IProject project = rsc.getProject();
        if(project.hasNature(CustomNature.NATURE_ID))
           return true;

    } catch (CoreException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Problem getting nature from IResource" + e.getMessage() , e);
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

and plugin.xml

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
 <propertyTester
       class="org.example.ui.propertytester.ProjectNaturePropertyTester"
       id="ProjectNaturePropertyTester"
       namespace="org.example.ui.propertytester"
       properties="checkProjectNature"
       type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
 </propertyTester>
```

and using it

```
<visibleWhen
             checkEnabled="false">
          <with
                variable="activeMenuSelection">
                <iterate>
                 <adapt
                         type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                      <test
                            property="org.example.ui.propertytester.checkProjectNature">
                      </test>
                   </adapt>
             </iterate>
                <count
                      value="1">
                </count>
          </with>
       </visibleWhen>
```

The result is working when selecting a file/folder in a project, the menu item will show up.

Answer (score 1):

Just test for adapting to `IResource` instead of `IProject`:

```xml
<adapt
    type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
    <test
        property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"
        value="customnature">
    </test>
 </adapt>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this yesterday and it did not work for me.. In my case, when the project is added with Java project nature by updating maven project then this will make the menu contribution disappear. any idea why?

Comment: Not sure. This code comes from one of the Ant plugins where it does work.